# Как отслеживать события кнопки подписки YouTube?

Tags: javascript, события, google-api, youtube

Мне нужно отслеживать нажатия на кнопку "Подписаться" от Google.
Вот [тут](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button) есть "генератор" кнопки и опция "Отслеживание нажатий".

У меня получается такой код:

```html
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

 <script>
   function onYtEvent(payload) {
  if (payload.eventType == 'subscribe') {
    // Add code to handle subscribe event.
 ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav-buttons');
  } else if (payload.eventType == 'unsubscribe') {
    // Add code to handle unsubscribe event.
  }
  if (window.console) { // for debugging only
    window.console.log('YT event: ', payload);
  }
   }
 </script>

 <div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data-layout="default" data-count="default" data-onytevent="onYtEvent"></div>
```

Событие должна отправлять строка `"ga('send'..."`. Код Google Analytics на сайте есть события через ссылку с `onclick` срабатывают, а кнопка с кодом выше — никак.

Подскажите, что делать?

Comment: Подсказали, что это баг гугл - https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5887

Comment: Может есть обходной путь?